# Formula of $\text{Var}[X|Y,Z]$ for $X\sim \mathcal N(\mu_X,\sigma_X^2)$, $Y\sim \mathcal N(\mu_Y,\sigma_Y^2)$, $Z\sim \mathcal N(\mu_Z,\sigma_Z^2)$?

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, variance, conditional-probability

How do I condition the **variance** of a normally distributed random variable on two other normally distributed random variables?

How do I condition the **expectation** of a normally distributed random variable on two other normally distributed random variables?

NOTE:
$Y$ and $Z$ are correlated ($\rho_{Y,Z}$)

Comment: Welcome to CV. What have you tried? Please tell us your attempts and also kindly add the  [tag:self-study] to your post.

Comment: Thank you. I added self-study. I was looking into the multivariate normal distribution and the multi-dimensional projection theorem, but I am not convinced I'm on the right track and, if I were, I do not know how to apply it here.

Comment: If the three together have a multivariate normal distribution with covariance matrix $\Sigma$ then you should probably say so

Comment: @Henry What do you mean by "together"?

Comment: By *together*, I am saying the joint random variable $(X,Y,Z)$ has a multivariate normal distribution on its support $\mathbb R^3$

Comment: I'd like my question to be addressed as comprehensively as possible, that is, in the case where the joint random variable exists but also in the case it does not (what's the difference?).